# 2 ajax forms on the same page

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to have 2 ajax forms on the same page? If so, is it common?

Just curious,
rodchar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  This site contains many forms on one page.  So if you visit this site a lot, its very common :)

All comments to posts are forms that use ajax.

Answer (score 0):

of course!! look at [Facebook](http://www.facebook.com), and look at every comment and answer on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's possible, but for more stability of code you sould not give them the same name.